# exceptional group via form preserving in magma

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups, magma-cas

let $K$ be the 27-dimensional complex vector space consisting of triples $m$ = ($m_1, m_2, m_3$) of complex 3 x 3-matrices $m_i$, $1 < i < 3$, where addition and scalar multiplication are defined coordinatewise. We define a cubic
form( ) on $K$ by $(m)= det(m_1) + det(m_2) + det(m_3) - tr(m_1m_2m_3)$. Then $3E_6(C)$ is the subgroup of $GL(K)$ preserving the form ( ).

I am new to Magma. My question is if one could construct the exceptional group via Magma by defining the form first and then letting Magma find elements in $GL(K)$ that preserve the form?

Comment: I have corrected your tag to refer to the Magma CAS (Computer Algebra System), but you may want to add a few more tags that are relevant to the actual mathematical content of your question.

Comment: I don't believe Magma has any way to compute the group preserving a cubic form over the complex numbers (though I could be wrong). I would suggest a different approach; you seem to know that the group will be $3E_{6}(C)$, so presumably you have a proof of this.

Comment: You could try using the internal Magma machinery to construct your group $3E_{6}(C)$, and then conjugate with a change-of-basis transformation (or otherwise define an explicit action on $K$) that matches with the form you are using.